# Report displays blank page on client machine

Tags: .net, wpf, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

My WPF project uses Crystal Reports. Everything works in development; the report loads and displays, and nothing is wrong with the DataSet. The following code calls the report:

```
 ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
     report.Load("../../CrystalReport.rpt");
     CustomerLedgerDataSet ds = new CustomerLedgerDataSet();
     DataTable dt1 = ds.BillProduct;
     DataTable dt2 = ds.Customer;
     foreach (var item in customer.CustomerCollection)
     {
       dt2.Rows.Add(item.Customerid, item.CustomerName, item.CustomerLocation,
                    item.Customerbalance, item.CustomerLastTally, item.Customerphone);
     }
     report.SetDataSource(ds);
     crystalReportsViewer2.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
```

This works in development but not when deployed on the client's PC. The report viewer shows up but with an empty report. The culprit is this line because it can't work out the path:

`report.Load("../../CrystalReport.rpt");`

[image]
[image]

I click once to publish for deployment and installed the same version of Crystal Runtime on the client PC.

Comment: Do you copy your reference DLLs ? Righ click on the reference, and choose the property. In the copy local field choose true.

Comment: They are already true especially the ones for crystal reports

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid using a lot of folders:**
try to copy you report in project folder itself. move it out from your report folder like this path

```
report.Load("~/CrystalReport.rpt")
```